# Text after "<" symbol gets truncated

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I found a problem with setting value in jsp. I have an element to be stored in database, if I provide its value with `"phenom<name"` In the database it saves as `"phenom<name"`.but while displaying data to user text after `"<"` symbol gets truncated and it displays as `"phenom<"` instead of `"phenom<name"`

Comment: I found a problem with setting value in jsp. I have an element to be stored in database, if I provide its value with "phenom<name" In the database it saves as "phenom<name".but while displaying data to user text after "<" symbol gets truncated and it displays as "phenom<" instead of "phenom<name"

Comment: If i add escape symbol "\" to "phenom<\name" then it will display properly but it will also store with escape symbol in DB which is not appropriate.

Comment: ``\`` is not an escape character in HTML, which is where you are experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it..

```
<c:out value="phenom<name" />
```

or

```
${fn:escapeXml('phenom<name')}
```

or

```
"phenom&lt;name"
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and post the result

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked :) you are great!